# Drive document doesn't display on Google Site

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites

When I try to insert a Google Drive document other viewers can't see it.

For example when I log out (or ask a friend to look at it) all I can see is an empty space where the document is supposed to be. However when log in I can see the document. I've ticked the "allow attachments" box and even when I go to options and look at a preview as a visitor I can see the document. I can't figure out why it doesn't work for other people. Has anyone experienced the same problem or does anybody know why it might not work?

Comment: What permissions does the document have in Drive.
And how are you doing the insert into the GoogleSites site?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the visibility setting is set to 'public on the web'. As mentioned above, you find this in the `File->Share` menu item.